# Prevent ASP.Net AppDomain Unload

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, appdomain

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661584/compiling-an-aspx-page-into-a-standalone-program/1687809#1687809), I'm writing a WinForms GUI that is run in an ASP.Net AppDomain.

However, whenever Web.config or the bin folder is modified, ASP.Net unloads the AppDomain, and the entire program dies.

Is there any way to prevent this?

**2<sup>nd</sup> EDIT**: In my EXE, I create the AppDomain by calling [`ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.applicationhost.createapplicationhost.aspx) and pass it a type in my EXE that launches the GUI.

**EDIT**: I'm already aware that this is a ***horrible*** design.
Does anyone have a sane alternatives?

The program tracks accounts for a non-profit organization in a typed dataset.
It needs to send bills by email, and I'm using ASPX files to generate the emails.  (I'd rather not change that, unless there's a very nice alternative; the templates have already been written)

The email templates are ASPX files that are deployed in a subfolder; that subfolder becomes the ASP.Net application and has the executable in its `bin` directory for ASP.Net to load all of my code into its AppDomain.

The typed dataset must be accessed by both the UI and the ASPX files, and I don't want to download the data from SQL server twice

Comment: You need some serious design review.  You should not do this.

Comment: I realize it's a horrible design, but I haven't found any alternative.  (Yet?)

Comment: Sane alternative: XML templates + XSLT for rendering? Better yet, try out CodeSmith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this question: [How to prevent an ASP.NET application restarting when the web.config is modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613824/how-to-prevent-an-asp-net-application-restarting-when-the-web-config-is-modified/629876#629876)

Answer (score 3):

This is core to ASP.Net - if the web.config is changed, the AppDomain is recycled.  If the machine.config is changed, *all* AppDomains are recycled.

However, you can disable this.  Turn on "Disable Recycling on Configuration Changes" for the application pool you are interested in in the IIS control panel.

[alt text http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/9938/iisdisablerecycle.png](http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/9938/iisdisablerecycle.png)

Comment: Read the question; I'm not using IIS.  Is there any way to configure that in ASP.Net itself?

Comment: I don't see anything in the question that indicates ISS being used or not.  For the record, exactly how are you launching the ASP.NET application domain, if not via IIS?

Comment: You're right; that was only in the linked question.  I'm launching the ASP.Net AppDomain by calling `ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost` in my EXE.

Comment: SLaks - the functionality you're after is inside System.Web.HttpRuntime.  I'm not sure you're going to have any luck modifying it, but you might try the approach in this thread: http://forums.iis.net/t/1121400.aspx

Comment: I looked inside HttpRuntime, but I didn't see anything like that.  I'll look at the thread.

Comment: System.Web.Runtime contains the FileSystemMonitor.  It's internal though (which explains why IIS can use it but you can't).  I'll be very interested to see if you get it working.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that your first question is dated **Oct 29**. I know it's far off on the development track...

But just out of curiosity: Why not use [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc308634.aspx)?

It's simple, fast, you can edit pretty much like an ASPX page, and it runs in whatever AppDomain you are.

Comment: This sounds interesting.  Can I distribute the templates with the program and run them at runtime? Also, can I get ASP.Net-style IntelliSense when editing the templates? (In Visual Studio)

Comment: Yes, T4 templates are simple text files. No, not natively, that is. There are intellisense for T4 from 3rd parties, though.

Comment: However, T4 templates require Visual Studio to execute; I don't want to require Visual Studio on my end user's machines.  Also, I use master pages, and I don't know how easily they would port to T4

Comment: No, T4 doesn't require Visual Studio to run. But, like I said... it's far off in the development track.

Comment: It doesn't? Can you give me a source?